# Assign pyarrow schema to pa.Table.from_pandas()

Tags: python, pandas, schema, parquet, pyarrow

I have a list column in my pandas dataframe along with int, string etc columns. I am able to convert string, date, int and timestamp columns. I want to know how to apply array() to the list column.

```
fields = [
    pa.field('id', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('secondaryid', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('date', pa.timestamp('ms')),
    pa.field('emails', pa.array())
]

my_schema = pa.schema(fields)

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(sample_df, schema=my_schema, preserve_index=False)
```

It asks for an object to be passed for the array.
I want to know how to apply schema for array of type string to 'emails' column, bearing in mind that I was write the table out to parquet format, so an empty array will result in SegFault. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply `pa.list_(pa.string())` instead of `pa.array`. `pa.array` is the constructor for a `pyarrow.Array` instance. This is the main object holding data of any type. In constrast to this, `pa.list_()` is the constructor for the LIST type. As its single argument, it needs to have the type that the list elements are composed of.

In Arrow terms, an *array* is the most simple structure holding typed data. It consists of a number of buffers of continuous memory. The primary buffer is always a bitmap indicating if a row is valid or null. Depending on the type of the array. There will be a single buffer for that data (e.g. for ints) or multiple ones for more complicated types. In contrast, the term *list* is used to describe what kind of data is stored in an array. LIST means that a single cell/row in a column can hold multiple values of the same kind.